# How to print two reference lists using two bib files and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I have two different bib files (`Literaturverzeichnis.bib` and `EigeneVeroff.bib`). The first one is my "normal" reference list and the other one is a second reference list, which includes my own publications. Now my problem is that I want to have two different reference lists at the end of the document, the second one at a new page, both with their own heading and both listed and numbered in the TOC. The references of the second bib file are not cited in the document, so I want all entries to show up automatically (normally this is done by `\nocite{*}`). I work with `biblatex`.

Now I tried (only an abstract - I think this is enough for understanding):

In the preamble:

```
\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis.bib}
\addbibresource{EigeneVeroeff.bib}
```

Then:

```
\begin {document}
...
\begin{refsection}[Literaturverzeichnis]
   \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]                  
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[EigeneVeroeff]
   \nocite{*}   
   \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{refsection}
...
\end {document}
```

Any ideas about what to do?

At this moment it only displays the heading (numbered as it should be) for the first reference list "Literaturverzeichnis" but with entries of the second reference list (EigeneVeroeff).

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer for my question on myself - the solution is:

in the preamble:

```
\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis.bib}
\addbibresource{EigeneVeroeff.bib}
```

then:

```
\begin {document}
...

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]                  

\begin{refsection}[EigeneVeroeff]
   \nocite{*}   
   \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title={Eigene Veröffentlichungen}]
\end{refsection}
...

\end {document}
```