# Separate multiple bib files reference using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have two .bib files and I can't seem to simply display **each** bibliography **separate**. I have searched on several forums but either I can't get the proposed solutions to work or they are quickly very complicated. I was just also imagining something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135952/how-to-print-two-reference-lists-using-two-bib-files-and-biblatex) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316422/separate-reference-list-based-on-multiple-bib-files) but I can't get it to work. What is missing? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib1.bib} 
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={first bibliography}, resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[title={second bibliography}, resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. From your links https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135952/how-to-print-two-reference-lists-using-two-bib-files-and-biblatex seems the most relevant. Could you explain what you mean exactly with "I can't get it to work"? Do you get errors? If yes, which errors? No output? Wrong output? If the output is wrong, then what does the output look like?

Comment: This is usually done by adding keywords via a Biber sourcemap, see the end of the accepted answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` already lets you filter by lots of properties, but not by file name of the containing `.bib` file.

If the crucial property that separates the two bibliographies can be read off from the data, it might be possible to code a solution that does not need to rely on the artificial separation into different files.

Still, [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864) explains how you can separate your bibliographies just by reference to the file names with a Biber sourcemap. The following just uses the new `appendstrict` feature to avoid clashes with existing noneempty `keywords` fields.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{bib1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, }, appendstrict]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=one, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{bib2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, }, appendstrict]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=two, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{bib1.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib2.bib}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  keywords     = {anotherkey},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}
Some citations: \autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}.
\printbibliography[title={First Bibliography}, keyword=one]
\printbibliography[title={Second Bibliography}, keyword=two]
\end{document}
```

[image: First Bibliography: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998)//Second Bibliography Nussbaum, Martha (1978).]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib1.bib} 
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[bib1]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={first bibliography}, resetnumbers=true]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[bib2]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={second bibliography}, resetnumbers=true]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```