# Multiple bibliographies working even if I use \nocite{*}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a huge latex project, which is divided in multiple parts. I want to have a .bib for each part and then display the references in this file in the end of the respective part.

I searched here for a solution but I didn't found any that worked in this way. Usually people have one single .bib file, and then do a bibliography after each part which contains all the stuff cited in the respective part. This doesn't work for me as I rarely cite stuff in the text.

I also don't want a global bibliography, so the labels can restart between parts.

Comment: Add a field value to the fieldset `keyword` at each entry, e.g. `keywords = {parti}`, `keywords = {partii}` etc. and then wherever you want to print bibliography, just use a filter: `\printbibliography[keyword=parti, title={References from Part I}]`. Since you don't reference anything in text, you probably have to use `\nocite{*}` before each execution of `printbibliography[...]` and may also need to add the option: `heading=subbibliography`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `refsection`s to create separate bibliographies per part of your document. With the optional argument of `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` you can fix one specific `.bib` file for that `refsection`. Then `\nocite{*}` will only use entries from that `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-one.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname-one.bib}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-two.bib}
@book{belk,
  author    = {Anne Belk},
  title     = {A Theory on Diplodocuses},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname-two.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[\jobname-one]
\part{One}
Lorem
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[\jobname-two]
\part{Two}
Ipsum
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two parts with one entry in the bibliography each.]

If you don't want to use `refsection`s because completely separate bibliographies are not desirable, you can look into solutions with `keyword`s based on file names like [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864) and [Separate multiple bib files reference using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596128/35864).